# Bound iteration through model's properties

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am building an admin component which builds a small form for editing the properties of an given model. Key to that is that it is model-independent and I'm almost there (I think) but I keep running into getting the binding to work correctly.

Here's the setup ... a template `action.hbs` makes reference to my component and passes in a `modelMeta` property (more on that in a sec):

```
{{model-admin-form
    model=content
    meta=modelMeta
}}
```

In the controller (`ActionController`) I define the `modelMeta` property as:

```
modelMeta: function() {
    var vals = [];
    var attributeMap = this.get('content.constructor.attributes');
    var self = this;
    attributeMap.forEach(function(name, value) {
        item = Ember.Object.create({
            name: value.name,
            type: value.type,
            value: self.get('content.' + name)
        });
        vals.push(item);
    });
    return vals;
}.property('content'),
```

This gives me an array of all the properties in the model and for each it gives me a "name", "type", and "value". This works great except that the "value" is not bound to the model. Ok, no problem, I'll just change the assignment line to:

```
valueBinding: self.get('content.' + name);
```

Nope. That doesn't work. Damn. Why not? Well using the Ember Inspector I can see that `valueBinding` is setup but it's `_from` property seems squiffy:

[image]

I'd have expected it to point to something like 'controllers.actions.content...' or something to that effect. Instead, the value of "Alt Gained" is the actual string value of the property but not a binding reference.

Can anyone help me?

=-=-=-=-=-=-=- UPDATE =-=-=-=-=-=-=-

I've updated the example a little to make more clear and add a little context. The end goal of this exercise is to provide a computed property `modelMeta` which is an array where each element in the array represents the meta-information for a property in the model. The meta information captured is:

- name: the property name
- type: the type of variable (e.g., String, Number, etc.)
- value/valueBinding: a bound reference to the named property on a model record

The first two are a piece of cake. The last one is the tricky part. Getting an unbound value is trivial too but binding it seems to be tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
var record = self.get('content'); // yes?
... Object.create({
  valueBinding: 'record.' + name,
  record: record // give the binding something to bind against
});
```

Here is what's going wrong in your code:

`value: self.get('content.' + name)` gets the property value too early, possibly before the model instance is populated. It definitely won't update if the model attribute changes.

`valueBinding: self.get('content.' + name)` doesn't work because it tries to establish a binding to whatever the *value* of the property is. Say `name` is `'email'`, then `self.get('content.' + name)` might be `'test@example.com'`, so `value` is now bound to a property called `'test@example.com'` (which is always undefined).

Answer (score 0):

```
var metaObject = Ember.Object.extend({
  value: Ember.computed.alias('item.name')
  // ^ same as saying valueBinding: 'item.name'
});


// Then in your model

modelMeta: function() {
  var attributeMap = this.get('content.constructor.attributes');
  var self = this;
  return attributeMap.map(function(name, value) {
    metaObject.create({
      item: item
    })
  });
}.property('content')
```

Not sure if I included all the properties you want, but you get the idea with the above. Pass the item into the instance `create()` and define the item bindings into the class definition.

Comment: I tried this but to no avail. Actually kind of feels like a step back only because I can no longer see the binding the Ember Inspector (not that I'd care if it worked). Let me add a little more context to the problem above so its clearer.

Comment: I've updated the example now. From your initial response I think I wasn't being clear enough that the "value.name" coming from the `attributeMap` is a property name of the model, which is then used as an offset to the "get" the appropriate value from model. That's what I want to bind to the `value` attribute of the `item`.